How to insert time formatted values into text in Excel
I have these rows that I would like to place in some other cell in the middle of some text, this is an example of my cells:




A
B
C
D




1
6201100010355
1
08:00:00
09:30:00


2
6201100010355
1
08:00:00
09:30:00



And I'm using this formula to do it:
="some text ("&A1&","&B1&","&C1&","&D1&")"

But the result is not what I expected, I get this:

some text (6201100010355,1,0,333333333333333,0,395833333333333)

What I would like to get is this:

some text (6201100010355,1,08:00:00,09:30:00)


Do you mean you want time values to be shows as time, not their numerical values?
="some text (" & A1 & ", " & B1 & ", " & TEXT(C1, "hh:mm:ss") & ", " & TEXT(D1, "hh:mm:ss") & ")"


It works with some changes, there were two  problems, the settings on my excel, which are Portuguese, so I had to switch the formula function names and separators to make it work. Something like ="some text ('"&B2&"',"&C2&",'"&TEXTO(D2;"hh:mm:ss")&"','"&TEXTO(E2;"hh:mm:ss")&"')". The single quotes are a late addition.

Try using the following:


="Some Text ("&B2&", "&C2&", "&TEXTJOIN(", ",,TEXT(D2:E2,"hh:mm:ss"))&")"


Or,
="Some Text ("&TEXTJOIN(", ",,TEXT(B2:E2,HSTACK(BASE(0,10,10),0,"hh:mm:ss","hh:mm:ss")))&")"


Though dates and times are entered using a specific format, such as "mm/dd" and "hh:mm:ss", and are displayed according to the regional format, they are stored as numbers. So, often when converting these to text we need to specify the format we want.
The other answers might be sufficient for your need, but here's one more way:

Dynamically expand the input by looking at the last non-blank cell in column D:
last_data_cell, XLOOKUP(TRUE, D:D <> "", D:D, , , -1)
Use a custom number format for time
It is an array formula, should work in Excel 2021 later

=LET(
    last_data_cell, XLOOKUP(TRUE, D:D <> "", D:D, , , -1),
    cells, A1:last_data_cell,
    delim, ",",
    timeformat, "hh:mm:ss;;;",
    text, INDEX(cells, , 1) & delim & INDEX(cells, , 2) &
        delim & TEXT(INDEX(cells, , 3), timeformat) &
        delim & TEXT(INDEX(cells, , 4), timeformat),
    IF(text <> ",,,", "some text (" & text & ")", "")
)


